# как передать данные в input datetime-local

Tags: javascript, html

У меня такая проблема. Не могу настроить опцию из выпадающего меню, чтобы при мануальном выборе времени оно перезаписывалось и попадало в инпуты. сейчас, если я ввожу начальную и конечную даты в инпут попадает время на текущий момент, а не выбранное

```
  <div>
  <input type="datetime-local" id="input1" required>
  <input type="datetime-local" id="input2" required>

  <select id="select">
    <option value="time" id="time">введите время</option>
    <option value="hour" id="hour">1 час</option>
    <option value="hours_8" id="hours_8">8 часов</option>
    <option value="day" id="day">1 день</option>
    <option value="days_30" id="days_30">30 дней</option>
  </select>
  <button type="button"></button>
</div>

const select = document.querySelector('#select');
    var from = new Date();
    var to = new Date();
    switch (select.value) {
        case 'hour':
            from.setHours(from.getHours() - 1)

            break;
        case 'hours_8':
            from.setHours(from.getHours() - 8)

            break;
        case 'day':
            from.setHours(from.getHours() - 24)

            break;
        case 'days_30':
            from.setHours(from.getHours() - 24 * 30)

            break;
        case 'time':
            Не знаю что тут нужно написать
        default:
            from.getTime()
            break;
    }

    formattedFrom = moment(from).format("YYYY-MM-DDTkk:mm");
    formattedTo = moment(to).format("YYYY-MM-DDTkk:mm");
    document.getElementById('listDateStart').value = formattedFrom;
    document.getElementById('listDateEnd').value = formattedTo;
```

Comment: Покажите код JS в котором вы пробовали?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [input type="datetime-locale" и выпадающий список](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1450530/input-type-datetime-locale-%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%be%d0%ba)

Answer (score 0):

```
 case 'time':
            from = new Date(document.getElementById("input1").value);
            to = new Date(document.getElementById("input2").value);
            
            break;
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]